# Regex pattern in Java to find and remove duplicate emails

Tags: java, regex

```
public String readEmails(String fileData) {

    String regex = "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9]"
            + "(?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?";

    String emails = "", emails2 = "";
    fileData = fileData.toLowerCase();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(fileData);
    while (m.find()) {
        emails += m.group()+", ";
    }

    return emails;
}
```

I am reading rtf file, finding emails and then storing into DB. I found one email is extracted two time I.e. HYPERLINK "mailto: aa@ymail.com" and then aa@ymail.com

How can I match two similar emails and keep one copy by removing all similar emails?

Comment: You will have a very hard time creating a RegEx which achieves this. You will be much better off matching all emails and then deleting duplicates in the database afterwards. Alternatively, at every match store the email in an array and every new match make sure it does not exist in this array before storing.

Comment: Hard to tell just what you are after.  I don't suppose you could write this in the form of a unit test or something?  If you are simply wanting to delete all mail with duplicate "mailto" addresses you will find a lot of false positives.

Comment: my database table column accepts unique emails as this is market "unique". I believe checking arrays or hashset if we alter little bit the regex pattern then it can be fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code as

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(fileData);
    while (m.find()) {
        String email = m.group();
        if (!set.contains(email)) {
           emails += email + ", ";
           set.add(email);
        }
    }

    return emails;
}
```

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Tomcat7.2\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes>javac *.java
UpdateNullEmails.java:71: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method contains()
location: interface java.util.Set<java.lang.String>
                        if (!set.contains()) {
                                ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

Comment: Now its printing unique email. Thanks from the bottom of my heart

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving emails as a string with commas:

1. Lower case them.
2. Store them in dictionary (HashSet) to deduplicate them
3. At the end, create output string out of the elements in dictionary.